# add properties to api gateway using python cdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

hi I want to add few properties to my api-gateway code like response body . I have added this using aws panel like this [manual configurations done using aws panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfM6w.png)

basically want to add a response body of 200 response and it's content type would be  application/json  and Models will be empty.  so any way to do this using cdk python ?

Answer (score 0):

see apigateway.MethodResponse in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/MethodResponse.html)

```
from aws_cdk import aws_apigateway as apigateway

# model: apigateway.Model

method_response = apigateway.MethodResponse(
status_code="statusCode",

# the properties below are optional
response_models={
    "response_models_key": model
},
response_parameters={
    "response_parameters_key": False
})
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply . as I want to return   `response body of 200 response and it's content type would be application/json`   what I can add this in function can you please guide ?

Comment: please guide ....